# Bridge Citrix Desktop Network to Host Computer

Tags: networking, vpn, citrix

The project I am currently working on requires me to use a Citrix desktop client.  While the Citrix desktop client isn't all that bad, I am not (nor will I ever be) an admin in that desktop environment.  As a developer - this couldn't be any more frustrating.  I tried fighting the battle with my network overlords, and realize its not worth the effort to try and get admin access.

On the computer I am launching the Citrix desktop client, I am an admin and have all the software I need to do my job.  The only thing Citrix gives me is access to urls/resources behind the firewall on the companies internal network.

Is there someway I can bridge the Citrix desktop client network to my computer.  For example, lets say there is a site on the internal network called gnarkill.com.  Right now, the only way I can access that site is by opening the Citrix desktop client, opening a browser in that client, and navigating to gnarkill.com.  I would like to be able to open a browser on my computer, and navigate to gnarkill.com.  I don't care that the Citrix desktop client might have to be open (but minimized)

There is no VPN.

Answer (score 0):

partially this is controlled via Policy on the Citrix XenDesktop\XenApp layer.

Your after what is called pass-through. ie. allowing you to have your desktop session interact with your local device. you could then pass through SMB connections to the hosting server.

Your issues is not strictly Citrix related. But company internal security, like for data leak prevention measures are in place it sounds like.

Another option would be to request having a the site exposed externally and navigate that way.

Other wise if they had a share you could pass-through to from your desktop client you could then finish the work in the XenDesktop session.